# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-5, ssms

Something must be wrong with my `ADDRESS` table's definition. When inserting or selecting rows, it is treating the `LINE1` column as `int`, but clearly I have declared it as `varchar(128)`.

This command works fine:

```
insert into address(PERSON_ID, LINE1, TYPE_ID) 
values (234, 'a', 1)
```

But in SQL Server Management Studio, when I do "Edit top 200 rows" and try to insert the same values, I get an error message.

After having inserted via SQL query, selecting rows from the table gives same error message.

Error message I get when inserting via SSMS Edit rows feature, or C#, and when selecting:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.

`ADDRESS` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESS]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PERSON_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LINE1] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [LINE2] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [CITY] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [COUNTY_ID] [int] NULL,
    [STATE] [int] NULL,
    [POSTAL_CODE] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [COUNTRY_ID] [int] NULL,
    [TYPE_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION]  AS ([dbo].[GET_ADDRESS_STRING]([ID])),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ADDRESS] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: might want to examine your `GET_ADDRESS_STRING` function

Comment: Be careful using that feature in SSMS. It would do you a lot of good to just write the update statement instead of using the Edit grid in SSMS.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for advice. this feature was only put to task for testing bare functionality. trust me, I'm not using  it to do anything else :)

Comment: 1) try removing your description field and try again.  
2) rename Line1  to address_line1 and try again
3) replace varchar with nvarchar....

can you display the Collation property for this database?

Comment: @JamieD77 4 eyes better than 2. That was it! thanks.